# How to create log file name with date and counter in log4cpp?

Tags: c++, log4cpp

I'm trying to use log4cpp.
I want to create log file name with this pattern:

Number_AppName_Date.log
Where:
Number - is a sequential increment number (each time the application us running this number will be incremented by 1)
AppName - Application Name 
Date - date.

1. How can I do it ?
2. Is it possible to do it via properties file ?